# how to get Parent-document only in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

any one can help me about this query
how can get Parent-document result using couchbase N1ql query

```
{
    "created_at": "2020-03-26T15:50:12.318Z",
      "created_by": 1,
      "deleted_at": "",
      "frm21_submit": null,
      "id": "6cb51519-7c6b-499d-8a8d-3c85658605fc",
      "machine_category_id": [
        "7a2eb767-faca-4762-b65b-2db9e1992c82",
        "259a4bcc-feb5-4d98-88c5-b331316e19be"
      ],

 "main_parts": [
    {
      "data": {
        "deleted_at": "777",
        "frm21_submit": null,
        "manufacturing_date": "03/31/2020",
        "model": "234234234",
        "photo": null,
        "serial_number": "324324234",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-31T14:11:48.909Z"
      },
      "id": "66354d7c-4769-4f3b-914e-bb841191e323"
    }
  ]

}
```

i want to desire to result only parent-document only field are all dynamic i can not selected field.

```
{
"created_at": "2020-03-26T15:50:12.318Z",
  "created_by": 1,
  "deleted_at": "",
  "frm21_submit": null,
  "id": "6cb51519-7c6b-499d-8a8d-3c85658605fc",
  "machine_category_id": [
    "7a2eb767-faca-4762-b65b-2db9e1992c82",
    "259a4bcc-feb5-4d98-88c5-b331316e19be"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want only remove main_parts from the original document.

Option 1: Select the fields you want. You mentioned this is not possible.

Option 2: SELECT all fields in the document 
        and project MISSING as the field you don't want

```
SELECT d.*, MISSING AS main_parts
FROM default AS d;
```

Option 3: Remove from the field from the object, if required do cascade using object functions https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/objectfun.html#object_remove

```
SELECT OBJECT_REMOVE(d,"main_parts").*
FROM default AS d;
```

Option 4: If you need to remove lot of fields use reconstruct object

```
SELECT  OBJECT v.name:v.val FOR v IN OBJECT_PAIRS(d) WHEN v.name NOT IN ["main_parts"] END.*
FROM default AS d;
```

Option 5: If you need to remove if field is object

```
SELECT  OBJECT v.name:v.val FOR v IN OBJECT_PAIRS(d) WHEN v.val IS NULL OR ISOBJECT(v.val) = false END.*
FROM default AS d;
```

Option 6: Based on value type

```
SELECT  OBJECT v.name:v.val 
            FOR v IN OBJECT_PAIRS(d) 
            WHEN type(v.val) IN ["null", "boolean", "number", "string", "array", "object"] 
         END.*
FROM default AS d;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) its working perfectly actually problem is fields and sub documents are not fixed. its can be increased . i am really thankful to you for help.